# How to update a notification when a service stopped - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service, android-notifications

I have a `Service` that downloads a database and displays a notification that contains a progress bar indicating download progress. I want to update that notification when the service stops abruptly like when user kills the app, or app gets killed in the background by the OS. The problem is that the service's `onDestroy` method never called, so I cannot update the notification and remove its progress bar.

I have tried overriding `onTaskRemoved` method of the `Service` and added `stopWithTask=true` in manifest but that didn't helped. I also overrided `onDestroy` method of the `Activity`, and put the code that updates the notification, but that also didn't work.

Here's my service:

```
public class DatabaseDownloadService extends IntentService {
    public static final int DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder;

    // For updating the UI on download progress.
    private ResultReceiver mResultReceiver;

    // If the service is stopped before download process is finished,
    // updates the notification.
    private boolean mCompleted;

    public DatabaseDownloadService() {
        super("DatabaseDownloadService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.print(getClass().getName(), "onHandleIntent");
        if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null)
            return;

        mResultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");

        // Some code that downloads the file...
    }

    private void shutdown() {
        if (!mCompleted) {
            mNotificationBuilder.setContentText("Download did not complete.")
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.error_color_red))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_pause)
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false);
            mNotificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotificationBuilder.build());
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.print(getClass().getName(), "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(); 
        startForeground(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.print(getClass().getName(), "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        // This is the code that updates the notification but onDestroy never gets called.
        shutdown();
    } 
}
```

It should update the notification when the app is killed by Android, or the user. But it doesn't.

How can I solve this issue? I have been searching for a solution for days, and didn't find one, so my only hope is StackOverflow.

Comment: How would a destroyed (or being destroyed) foreground service display the notifications? You aren't supposed to do anything but clean up in your onDestroy().

Comment: @Steven I thought about it, but couldn't figure out how can I display the notification just before the application or the service gets killed.

Comment: Why not use a bound service and have your service do only one thing: download the database. Then since its a bound service you can communicate the progress easily and notify if it is about to be destroyed.

Comment: @Steven Yes, it's better to have single responsibility. I use ResultReceiver for notifying the progress, but would it make any difference if service's onDestroy method never gets called?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the services onDestroy method never gets called because you shouldn't be using OnDestroy like that. You are not even guaranteed that the Service's onDestroy will be called. Use bound services.

Comment: @Steven Thanks, I'll try it.